# Copying image file in perl

Tags: perl

I'm a perl newbie. I need to do the following:

```
my $path=$insfn{'upload'.$i}; // this references the path for the uploaded image file
```

I need to take the contents of this path (it is an image), and fill it in a new file.

Here is as far as Ive gotten:

```
my $random = '/path/6dadasd.jpg';
open(my $fh,'>',$random){
    print $fh ? how do i get the contents of $path?
}
```

**I have no idea how to do this in Perl.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why the downvotes? the question is pretty clear IMO

Comment: @TudorConstantin I made updates to it.

Comment: @TudorConstantin: It seems some angry people down votes every `perl` question. On other threads I do not saw such down votes on question as on `perl`. It seems they down votes against perl not question.

Comment: I hope that's not true. I get much more upvotes on my answers on Perl than on any other languages - the Perl community seems more fair play

Comment: Does this question show any research effort? No. Is it clear? No. Why, then, should it receive any upvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking how to copy a file from the path in `$path` to the path in `$random`. You can use [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Copy)'s `copy` for that.

```
use File::Copy qw( copy );

copy($path, $random)
   or die("Can't copy \"$path\" to \"$random\": $!\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve that with shell help:

```
# This
`cp "$path" "$random"`
# Or this
`cat "$path" > "$randorm"`

# Or Pure Perl
my $path = '/path/src';
open my $src, '<', $path;
my $content = do{ local $/; <$src> };
my $random = '/path/dst';
open my $fh,'>',$random;
print $fh $content;
```